# Breaking lists at index

Tags: performance, haskell

I have a performance question today.

I am making a (Haskell) program and, when profiling, I saw that most of the time is spent in the function you can find below. Its purpose is to take the nth element of a list and return the list without it besides the element itself. My current (slow) definition is as follows:

```
breakOn :: Int -> [a] -> (a,[a])
breakOn 1 (x:xs) = (x,xs)
breakOn n (x:xs) = (y,x:ys)
 where
  (y,ys) = breakOn (n-1) xs
```

The `Int` argument is known to be in the range `1..n` where `n` is the length of the (never null) list `(x:xs)`, so the function never arises an error.

However, I got a poor performance here. My first guess is that I should change lists for another structure. But, before start picking different structures and testing code (which will take me lot of time) I wanted to ask here for a third person opinion. Also, I'm pretty sure that I'm not doing it in the best way. Any pointers are welcome!

*Please, note that the type `a` may not be an instance of `Eq`.*

### Solution

I adapted my code tu use `Sequence`s from the [Data.Sequence](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Sequence.html) module. The result is here:

```
import qualified Data.Sequence as S

breakOn :: Int -> Seq a -> (a,Seq a)
breakOn n xs = (S.index zs 0, ys <> (S.drop 1 zs))
 where
  (ys,zs) = S.splitAt (n-1) xs
```

However, I still accept further suggestions of improvement!

Comment: why not use the standart funktions? breakOn n l = (take n l,drop n l)

Comment: @nist That doesn't have the right type. mhwombat's answer below does.

Comment: Because I need to retain the nth element and end up with all elements before and after the extracted element in a single list.

Comment: OK, thanks! I didn't know it! Done!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is inefficient. You can do a bit better by using `splitAt` (which unboxes the number during the recursive bit), a lot better by using a data structure with efficient splitting, e.g. a [fingertree](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.5.2.1/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html), and best by massaging the context to avoid needing this operation. If you post a bit more context, it may be possible to give more targeted advice.

Comment: OK, this was a huge performance improvement! I adapted my program to use `Sequence`s everywhere. Now it performs **much better**. Interestingly, now it takes more time generating random numbers than splitting lists. Hurray! My remaining question is *why lists are the default method?*.

Comment: @DanielDíaz Because they're very simple (both, to use and to implement). And they're fast enough for many many uses. Just, indexing isn't one of those.

Comment: I really must object, there are entirely too many people named Daniel here for me to keep track of. >:[

Comment: @C.A.McCann I disagree. Daniel and Daniel are well known to you being top notch Haskell answerers, and Daniel, as OP is highlighted blue, and stands out as a cheerful, open-minded, fast learning OP. I see no cause for confusion. By the way, Daniel, if you keep learning fast you'll end up as insightful as Daniel and Daniel are.

Answer (score 4):

Prelude functions are generally pretty efficient. You could rewrite your function using `splitAt`, as so:

```
breakOn :: Int -> [a] -> (a,[a])
breakOn n xs = (z,ys++zs)
 where
  (ys,z:zs) = splitAt (n-1) xs
```

Comment: Thanks, this version is a bit more efficient, but still slow. I'm using big lists here. I'm going to try with the `Data.Sequence` module as suggested by Daniel Wagner.

Comment: The problem with this version is the right appending (I think).

Comment: @DanielDíaz No, that is fine. The only problem with this version is that getting at the `n`-th element of a list is an `O(n)` operation. If that's not fast enough, you need a different data structure. `Data.Sequence` is a good first candidate.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, I'm trying to adapt the whole code to Data.Sequence to try it. Right now I'm trying to implement `mapM` for the `Seq` type.